# Geting console warnings 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' while updating UITableView's cell programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have created a Cell Which Have one UIView.

Here is the image: [image]

In `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am calling an `-updateData` selector which make some labels in it. And once all Labels are added I am increasing the height constraint of `tableViewCell` (I have made an outlet of Height Constraint)

Following are the last two lines of my `-updateData` Selector:

```
self.cellHeightConstraint.constant = yPosition + Padding;
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

**Edit**

Here is my Table View configuration for Autolayout:

```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90;
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell];
    [cell updateDataWithBillDetail:wrapper];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

When I run this code I am getting following warning:

```
  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13d8f9cf0 V:[UIView:0x13d8fb090(114)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13d8fb200 UIView:0x13d8fb090.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13d8faf10.topMargin - 8>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13d8fb250 V:[UIView:0x13d8fb090]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x13d8faf10 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13db6cd80 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x13d8faf10(35.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13d8f9cf0 V:[UIView:0x13d8fb090(114)]>

 Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
 The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Can someone helps me how can I remove this console warning?

Comment: This can be due to the `height` returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` does not matches the one set by the `height constraint`
Can you share some related code

Comment: why -8 in your constrains (...but thats another thing)? just to test it out, have you tried to just give the cell a width and height constraint?

Comment: @zero3nna yes If I don't call my `-updateData` method then No warnings are coming.

Comment: have you set your Row Height to custom in the Storyboard/XIB? Inside the Size Inspector of your Table View Cell?

Comment: @zero3nna yes I Have

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the yPosition. Replace it with initial cell's height.

Comment: I have to change the cell's height based on new content.

Comment: Thats what I am telling. Your code has a line self.cellHeightConstraint.constant = yPosition + Padding; Remove the "yPosition" and replace it with your tableview cell's initial height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you even do this for a cell, it prob. conflicts with the height like @ystack sad.
Have you tried to work with dynamic cell sizes?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your time. Actually my cell's height is calculated by Autolayout so I haven't implemented this method.